# Set and use variable in RUN instruction using Windows cmd as shell

Tags: docker, cmd

This is a MWE of my Dockerfile: (I'm hand-composing, not using `docker-compose`)

```
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019-amd64
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
RUN set zz=foo && echo %zz%
```

When I build the container, I expect this to print `foo`, but instead I get `%zz%` which seems to indicate that `echo` doesn't see the variable `zz` set.

```
Step 20/24 : RUN set zz=foo && echo %zz%
 ---> Running in b1f462e81c5c
%zz%
Removing intermediate container b1f462e81c5c
 ---> 9c0abf6eb928
```

If I run this on the command line, it works as expected:

```
C:\> cmd /S /C set zz=foo && echo %zz%
foo
```

How can I make the `RUN` instruction work like the command prompt?

---

My actual use case, in case this is an XY problem: I'm reading the contents of a user-provided file into a variable and then using that in a command which sets some global config file.

```
RUN `
  set /p pat=<your_pat.txt && `
  git config --global url."https://%pat%@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

Comment: I suggest putting your commands inside a script, and calling that script in one command. Are you running Windows containers?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson yes, following [this template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2022) to build a Visual Studio project in a container

Comment: What about using ```SHELL ["cmd", "/V", "/S", "/C"]``` and ```RUN set zz=foo && echo !zz!```.